# how to reorder of rows of a dataframe based on values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A  B  C  D
b  3  3  4
a  1  2  1
a  1  2  1
d  4  4  1
d  1  2  1
c  4  5  6
```

Now I hope to reorder the rows based on values in column A.

I don't want to sort the values but reorder them with a specific order like `['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']`
what I expect is:

```
A  B  C  D
b  3  3  4
d  4  4  1
d  1  2  1
c  4  5  6
a  1  2  1
a  1  2  1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good use case for [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), since you have ordered categories. Just make that column a categorical and mark `ordered=True`. Then, `sort_values` should do the rest.

```
df['A'] = pd.Categorical(df.A, categories=['b', 'd', 'c', 'a'], ordered=True)
df.sort_values('A')
```

If you want to keep your column as is, you can just use `loc` and the indexes.

```
df.loc[pd.Series(pd.Categorical(df.A, 
                                categories=['b', 'd', 'c', 'a'], 
                                ordered=True))\
         .sort_values()\
         .index\
       ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Without changing datatype of A, you can set 'A' as index and select elements in the desired order defined by sk.

```
sk = ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']
df.set_index('A').loc[sk].reset_index()
```

Or use a temp column for sorting:

```
sk = ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']
(
    df.assign(S=df.A.map({v:k for k,v in enumerate(sk)}))
    .sort_values(by='S')
    .drop('S', axis=1)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionary like mapping for order of strings then sort the values and reindex:

```
order = ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a']
df = df.reindex(df['A'].map(dict(zip(order, range(len(order))))).sort_values().index)

print(df)
   A  B  C  D
0  b  3  3  4
3  d  4  4  1
4  d  1  2  1
5  c  4  5  6
1  a  1  2  1
2  a  1  2  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61335688/7782271) provided by [rafaelc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2535611/rafaelc) a step further. If you want to do it in a chained process, here is how you'd do it:

```
df = (
    df
        .assign(A = lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['A'], categories = ['b', 'd', 'c', 'a'], ordered = True))
        .sort_values('A')
)
```